# Datareader perform dynamic calculation

Tags: c#, sqldatareader, datareader, large-data

I am trying to read and process a large data result. I am using a datareader to read items record by record however I need to process a calculation within my process. Example in order to process a dynamic field that I will create called "Name" is will take the result from the datareader FirstName + " " + LastName.

Can anyone please help guide me to get this to work. I am not sure how to achieve the results that I am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Place the calculation in your SQL.

```
SELECT *, FirstName + ' ' + LastName AS FullName
FROM   table
WHERE  where-clause
ORDER BY order-by-clause
```

To address @JoelCoehoorn's concern:
For those that absolutely *must* do this in C#:

inside your loop over SqlDataReader add:

```
string fullName = reader["FirstName"] + " " + reader["LastName"];
```

or if you are using the latest C# (VS2015 and later):

```
string fullName = $"{reader["FirstName"]} {reader["LastName"]}";
```

Comment: This is almost certainly the easiest and quickest answer (+1!), but if you need to really scale up big you'll usually do better doing this on the client/C# side.

Comment: Agreed.  I figured by the time someone was at the giant-scale they'd already have figured that out.

Comment: I am using VS2013 an I can't perform that method as the calculation is dynamic based on user input. I would need to have this section be dynamic: reader["FirstName"] + " " + reader["LastName"];

Comment: Its *your* code, @Paul.  You can make it as "dynamic" or lifeless as you want.